# What is the difference between the cloud disks supported by Alibaba Cloud?

Tags: ssd, cloud-computing, cloud-storage, alibaba-cloud

When creating an ECS instance on Alibaba Cloud, I often get an option to choose a cloud disk e.g. from Ultra Cloud disk and SSD cloud disk.

What is the difference between these cloud disks and what kind of implications do they have on the performance of a website or web application.[See Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOCWn.png)

Answer (score 2):

These is the difference between SSD and Ultra Cloud Disk:

SSD Cloud Disk: High-performance disks with stable and high random I/O performance and high data reliability. It handles 20,000 read/write IOPS, 300 Mbps throughput by using Alibaba Cloud's Apsara Distributed Technology. (advanced feature)

Ultra Cloud Disk: With high cost performance, medium random I/O performance, and high data reliability. (cost efficient purpose)

for more details: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/40551.htm

Hope it helps you.

Comment: In short, SSD is faster but costs more than Ultra.